# ¿Cómo importar proyecto a Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, zip

Tengo un proyecto winRAR.zip que quiero abrir en Netbeans, lo copio en la carpeta de Netbeans projects lo extraigo alli, voy al Netbeans en abrir proyecto y no me aparece el proyecto con la taza solo la carpeta, qué hago mal?

Comment: Busca la opción `Import Project` o `Import` o similar.

Comment: Voy a ver,gracias por contestar tan rápido

Comment: Me aparece no netbeans project added, no se por qué

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para importar un proyecto Java a Netbeans se usa :

<kbd>**File**</kbd> > <kbd>**Import Project**</kbd> > Escoges tu tipo de proyecto, en tu caso debes usar la opción "**From ZIP...**".

***No debes descomprimir el archivo.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ok gracias,ya me ha dejado, un saludo.

Comment: @spain21 Bienvenido a es.stackoverflow si alguna la respuesta ayudo a solucionar tu problema puedes hacer upvote y/o aceptarla, puede haber respuestas que ayuden a solucionar tu pregunta de una forma y otras que la complementen, si crees que ayudan de alguna manera no dudes en, upvote y/o aceptar puedes mirar este link es.stackoverflow.com/tour (veo que ya lo has visitado) este sistema ayuda a otros visitantes con tu mismo problema a identificar una solucion rapidamente.Saludos

Comment: Elenasys offtopic usas Netbeans? has mirado Intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux una maravilla jaja Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel que tal, uso los 2 pero definitivamente como comentas es mejor Intellij IDEA, de hecho de el se basaron para Android Studio que estoy utilizando actualmente, saludos!

Comment: yo tambien uso los dos, asi el cambio de uno a otro no tengo que pensar donde estan las cosas pues son muy similares y el diseño de la UI un 10, bueno un 9 para que no se les suba a la cabeza jaja.